# Why is my OnePlus One phone's camera generating dark pictures?

Tags: camera-settings, cameraphones, smartphone

I own a OnePlus One. As per the [specification](https://oneplus.net/one) mentioned on the OnePlus site, it is set to capture high quality pictures. But when I take pictures from my phone (unless I have more than enough light or I am clicking a stable object) it creates relatively dark pictures or blurred pictures (when object is moving). But the spec says that it can shoot 4K videos.
I've also seen the same behavior with video capturing. It is always dark. However, in the same lighting condition my other phone, a Samsung S Duos 2, gives me results somewhat equivalent to my DSLR (Nikon D3300). Do I need to make changes in the camera settings?

Comment: Please post example images with the EXIF intact. We have no way of guessing what may or may not be the issue since we have no clues as to what settings you have or what the scene that you are trying to capture is. Secondly, video isn't on topic on this site, see http://video.stackexchange.com for questions related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be any number of different issues, but my two best guesses would be user error and or a very challenging scene that is beyond the capabilities of your smartphone camera.

Considering that the OnePlus One uses the [Sony Exmor IMX214 CMOS sensor](http://www.sony.net/Products/SC-HP/new_pro/april_2014/imx214_e.html), also used in the popular Nexus 6 - it is doubtful that this is due to some overarching hardware constraint that across the board will produce underexposed images.

As can be seen in [many online reviews](http://robinwong.blogspot.com/2014/09/oneplus-one-camera-review.html) of the OnePlus One camera, it is very capable in normal shooting conditions and I see no one else complain of underexposure across all images.

Keep in mind that the OnePlus One uses its own CyanogenMod custom camera interface that you won't find on other Android implementations of this camera sensor, so that brings up a bit of a challenge to those of us not intimately familiar with your particular phone.

What I would recommend is utilizing the built in exposure compensation adjustment to test out overexposing the scene. I also would recommend visiting your app store and testing out a few different camera applications that likely are far superior to the built in one, which I would guess a variety of them do offer exposure compensation. Typically the exposure compensation on modern cameras is denoted by a +/- graphic such as the following:

[image]

Comment: Again, if you post example images with the EXIF data available and explain to us what settings (if any) you have modified in the default camera app of your OnePlus One, we can provide better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer this question without some example images with EXIF information.  I would be guessing that the metering system of the "oneplus" is simply defaulting to a lesser exposure.  Cameras do not all meter a scene ( determine the exposure settings ) the same way.

If you check your manual in detail you may find options to adjust the exposure ( e.g exposure compensation ), however not all systems allow that.